# Decreasing kernel if and only if sine transform is positive?

Tags: inequality, fourier-transform

Suppose $f(t) \ge 0$ for $t\ge 0$, is it the case that $$\int_0^\infty f(t) \sin(x t) dt \ge 0$$ if and only if $$\frac{d}{dt}f(t) \le 0\ \ ?$$

One direction is fairly trivial involving an alternating series. The other direction is not so obvious, if it is even true. Does anyone have a proof or a reference?

Comment: I would guess that something like $f(t) = \sin(t)^2/t^2$ is a counterexample (for $x=1$). Or do you mean that the integral is non-negative for all $x$?

Comment: Oh, so it isn't true. What is $\int_0^\infty f(t) \sin(x t)$?